# Migrating local database to Azure ClearDb through mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, azure, database-migration

I have been trying this but no success, i get to this stage and no further.
[image: Screenshot of Workbench]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to migrate from local database to azure cleardb, simply use the mysqldump utility in conjunction with the mysql command line client. For example:

mysqldump --single-transaction -u (old_database_username) -p -h (old_database_host) (database_name) | mysql -h (cleardb_host) -u (cleardb_user) -p -D (cleardb_database)

But if you insist on using MySQL Workbench then this might be of help - 
http://nullsession.com/2014/02/04/downgrading-you-cleardb-mysql-database-in-azure/

Comment: Add a summary of the linked article.